# I don't know how to connect one of the .html files from the quiz application to the django application. (Page not found (404))

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, http-status-code-404

I have a quiz_app (situated in the QuizApp folder) inside my (Django) basic_app. Everything is working fine up to the moment, where the game ends and the quiz_end.html (previously end.html) page is not displaying.

This link is pointing to quiz_game.js and it (the link) is situated inside the quiz_game.html file - (quiz_js is in this case a folder situated inside the django´s static folder)

```
<script src="{% static "quiz_js/quiz_game.js" %}">
```

Here is some kind of link to the end.html file (please note, that the end.html will soon be renamed to quiz_end.html file) and the link is situated inside the quiz_game.js file - (it is a part of the if statement - if there are no question left, then the game ends)

```
if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
    //go to the end page
    return window.location.assign("/end.html");
};
```

(You can see the full code of this file here - https://github.com/jamesqquick/Build-A-Quiz-App-With-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript/blob/master/Quiz%20App%20Master/game.js - it´s just called game.js instead of quiz_game.js + You can see all of the files from the Quiz App here - https://github.com/jamesqquick/Build-A-Quiz-App-With-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript/tree/master/Quiz%20App%20Master - The only difference is, that I have to put the .css and .js files to the Django´s static folder)

I have renamed the end.html file to quiz_end.html and since I am using Django, I was trying to incorporate Django´s template tag into the quiz_game.js file like this - (I am not sure, if I am doing it right, but it is a standart url tag, which works when being added to .html files, but I am not sure, if it is the right way to add it to the .js files)

```
getNewQuestion = () => {

  if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
      localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
      //go to the end page
      return window.location.assign("{% url 'quiz_end' %}");
  };
```

The thing is, that this is my first time, when I am trying to redirect the browser from .js file to .html file while using Django and I do not really know, how to do it.

The view and the url pattern of the quiz_end.html file should be fine. Here they are -

```
def quiz_end(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/QuizApp/quiz_end.html')
```

and

```
url(r'^quiz_end/$', views.quiz_end, name='quiz_end'),
```

I also don´t know, why is the browser still redirecting me to /end.html instead of redirecting me to /quiz_end.html, when the game is finished.

Could anybody help me please? Thank You very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was solved by adding app's namespace to urls and calling it like this:

```
{% url 'quiz_app:quiz_end' %}
```

Comment: How should I add the quiz_app's namespace, when I already have this (app_name = 'basic_app') line of code there?

Comment: This is the urls.py of the core app: `path('quiz_app/', include('quiz_app.urls', namespace='quiz_app')),

Comment: I am getting this error: NameError: name 'path' is not defined :/

Comment: After adding this line of code - from django.urls import path - I am getting a new error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quiz_app'

Comment: quiz_app was just an example. If you app is called 'quiz' you should put 'quiz' there. I tried to make it obvious that the route goes through the urls of the 'quiz', then it looks up the name 'quiz_end' (inside the path) and from there it goes to the view. And lastly the view serves the template